# Excel VBA with fill right

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

This is my code it works but the data is so large that it takes awhile to run this. After i select the filter criteria what i need to do is select all of the filterd data in Column F minus the header then fill that into Column G. The data changes daily so one day filtered data may start at F1590 then next day F1580 etc. When i fill right though I need it to fill into the same cells in Column G.

```vb
Sub ScrubbingOptimized()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim FilteredDataRange As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    
    ' Disable screen updating to improve performance
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Find the last row in column A (assuming it contains the data)
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Apply the filter criteria to column AB (Field 24)
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AB$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:="=No", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
    
    ' Apply the filter criteria to column G (Field 7)
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AB$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "ALL SUPERVISORS", "IN-PLANT SUPPORT", "MAIN DISTRIBUTION TOUR-I", _
        "MAIN DISTRIBUTION TOUR-II", "MAIN DISTRIBUTION TOUR-III", _
        "MAINTENANCE OPERATIONS"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    
    ' Find the first cell with filtered data in column F (excluding header)
    Set FilteredDataRange = Columns("F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    If Not FilteredDataRange Is Nothing Then
        ' Loop through each visible cell in column F
        For Each Cell In FilteredDataRange
            ' Fill right in column G for the current cell in column F
            Cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, Cell.MergeArea.Cells.Count).Value = Cell.Value
        Next Cell
    End If
    
    ' Clear the filters
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    ' Re-enable screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I have tried to copy a range and paste but when I do that the data in Column G will not match up with Column F. I have tried another code to where I can select all the cells as if I were to press control shift down but then I cannot get it to fill right.

Answer (score 1):

### Copy a Filtered Column to Another Column

[image]

```vb
Sub ScrubbingOptimized()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    ' Filter column 'X'.
    trg.AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:="=No", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
    ' Filter column 'G'.
    trg.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "ALL SUPERVISORS", "IN-PLANT SUPPORT", "MAIN DISTRIBUTION TOUR-I", _
        "MAIN DISTRIBUTION TOUR-II", "MAIN DISTRIBUTION TOUR-III", _
        "MAINTENANCE OPERATIONS"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    
    Dim frg As Range:
    With ws.AutoFilter.Range.Resize(trg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).Columns("F")
        On Error Resume Next
            Set frg = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False ' turn off the auto filter
    ' or just
    'ws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData ' clear the filters
    
    Dim WasScrubbed As Boolean
    If Not frg Is Nothing Then
        Dim arg As Range
        For Each arg In frg.Areas
            arg.Offset(, 1).Value = arg.Value ' copy values from 'F' to 'G'
        Next arg
        WasScrubbed = True
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    If WasScrubbed Then
        MsgBox "Optimized was scrubbed .", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "Optimized had already been scrubbed.", vbExclamation
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Columns("F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` returns not only cells that meet filter criteria in the data table, but also a large number of unused cells below the data table. This causes the code to process invalid empty cells, resulting in lower efficiency.

- minimize `FilteredDataRange` to reduce looping time
- collect all values in an array and write to Column G all at time

```vb
Sub ScrubbingOptimized()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim FilteredDataRange As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim arrG, rArea As Range
    ' Disable screen updating to improve performance
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Find the last row in column A (assuming it contains the data)
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arrG = ActiveSheet.Range("$G$1:$G$" & LastRow).Value
    ' Apply the filter criteria to column AB (Field 24)
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AB$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:="=No", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
    ' Apply the filter criteria to column G (Field 7)
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AB$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "ALL SUPERVISORS", "IN-PLANT SUPPORT", "MAIN DISTRIBUTION TOUR-I", _
        "MAIN DISTRIBUTION TOUR-II", "MAIN DISTRIBUTION TOUR-III", _
        "MAINTENANCE OPERATIONS"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    ' Find the first cell with filtered data in column F (excluding header)
    Set FilteredDataRange = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Columns("F")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If Not FilteredDataRange Is Nothing Then
        ' Loop through each visible cell in column F
        For Each rArea In FilteredDataRange.Areas
            For Each Cell In rArea.Cells
            ' Fill right in column G for the current cell in column F
                arrG(Cell.Row, 1) = Cell.Value
            Next Cell
        Next rArea
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Range("$G$1:$G$" & LastRow).Value = arrG
    ' Clear the filters
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    ' Re-enable screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```